# Who pays for transit between airports when connecting from PVG to SHA with China Eastern?

Tags: air-travel, transit, airport-transfer, shanghai

I am flying from Tokyo (Haneda Airport) to Delhi via Shanghai.

#### Question

In Shanghai, I am landing at Hongqiao International Arpt (SHA) and departing from Pudong International Arpt (PVG). Flying on China Eastern. Is the airline bound to pay for/arrange the transit between the airports?

#### My previous experience

Last time when I had to make this transit in Shanghai, I had only about 2-3 hours in early morning. I had looked for a Shuttle Bus at the terminal but could not find one. The people at the airport were not helpful at all. Because the time was running out, I had to take a Taxi which ended up costing USD 50!!

I will have to make this transit again this weekend. I looked up the Airport website. The shuttle bus costs about 5 USD (30 RMB). A taxi should cost around 20-30 USD. Am I expected to bear this cost?

Could not find any information on the China Southern Airlines website.

**Edit**:
It's a point to point ticket from Tokyo to Delhi. I had my reasons for booking this particular itinerary involving an airport change which are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: In _general_ - although this isn't from specific experience with this airport/airline - the airline should cover your transit if you booked the tickets on one itinerary. If transit times cause you to miss your flight, the airline also has to sort this out. If however you have booked the tickets on separate itineraries, it's up to you.

Comment: Is this a point-to-point itinerary? Do you have two separate tickets; one from Tokyo to SHA, and another from PVG to Delhi?

Comment: @TimMalone I wouldn't say that in general. I've transferred in London, Paris and New York on a single ticket and had to bear cost of transport. It's true they'll rebook you if you miss your flight on one ticket though.

Comment: Under what reasoning would one come to the conclusion that such transfers reasonably should be paid by anybody other than the passenger? The same reasoning would probably apply to any other expenses incurred during any layover, or also to transportation to/from the departure/arrival airport.

Comment: The cheapest way to go between two airports is travelled by Metro Line2, it takes 1.5-2hrs. The fastest and most reliable way is Metro Line2+Maglev Train. Be aware of traffic congestion when travelled by taxi/bus.

Comment: To make an edit please log in with your account that you used to ask the question! Suggested edit is: "Edit: It's a point to point ticket from Tokyo to Delhi. I had my reasons for booking this particular itinerary involving an airport change which are irrelevant to the question."

Comment: @fkraiem I would agree, if there were two separate tickets, but this is _one ticket._ I think that implies continuous conveyance from arrival at the departure gate of Flight One to arrival at the destination gate of Flight Two.

Answer (score 13):

Original Poster posting the experience this time.

**The airline paid for the transfer. You have to ask for it.**

1. I arrived at the SHA airport terminal 1.
2. Took the free bus shuttle to T2, took 15 mins.  (Shuttle to PVG only runs from T2)
3. Went to the China Eastern Airlines Check In Desk.
4. Asked for a bus pass to PVG airport.
5. They gave me one after checking my boarding pass till SHA and the ticket for the rest of journey from PVG.
6. Took the bus from T2 of SHA to PVG, took about 90 mins.  (Runs from waiting room 2, first floor)
7. Checked in at PVG.

Note:

1. There was no traffic. It was a Saturday evening. (Started at about 5:30 PM)
2. If you don't ask for the bus pass you won't get one.
3. Even if you know very LITTLE Chinese, it would be a BIG help.

For my return journey, both my arrival and departure are from the same SHA airport, so that's a relief :)